# COM port is in use

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to connect a printer in a COM port. The requirement is that COM port has to be single digit (betweem COM1 to COM9). I am trying to assign single digit to the COM ports but they show in use. I am not sure which hardware devices are using this COM ports.

How can I find that which device is using which COM port? Also how I can remove the non-used COM port so I can use it for COM port which is connected to the printer?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx)