# C# Closing the serial port when no one is using it

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an object of SerialPort. It is used by multiple object of some class. Is there some elegant solution to close the port when no one is using it?

The only thing i came up is straightforward: write some manager class above SerialPort with users counter.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how i can put a comment, i search but i dont find. So the answer, if you use from the same class, alway when you finish to use you close, and if are multiple user to use at the same time you can see if is busy or not the SerialPort. So when your are go to use you check if is busy, and when you finish you close. If you need some code tell me and i write to you.

Comment: I need my serial port to be always open and used by several users within my program.

Comment: If your try tell me way you need always open the port, i think that this can help. Other way that you can do is make a timer that check and close, but your elegant solution, i think, is close when you dont need. here exist several links to close and open serial. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195483/c-check-if-a-com-serial-port-is-already-open , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856402/com-port-is-in-use ,